# HTML table in Tooltip not showing using Bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

After trying to set up custom HTML table in a `tooltip box` for a couple of hours, I realized the `Bootstrap` version seems to solve the problem. Indeed, this is perfectly working under `Boostrap 4.0.0` but not under `Bootstrap 4.3.1`.

Is it a bug ? or am I missing something ?

Here the code:

```js
/** Tooltip */
$(function() {
  $('.my_tooltip').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    html: true,
    title: `Colors explanation:
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='color-box bg-green'></div>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:left;'>Green : available</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='color-box bg-orange'></div>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:left;'>Orange : pre-booked</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='color-box bg-red'></div>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:left;'>Red : booked</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    `
  });
});


/* Load icons */
feather.replace();
```

```css
.bg-green {
  background: green;
}

.bg-orange {
  background: orange;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.color-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO">


<!------------------------------------------------------------->
<i data-feather="help-circle" class="my_tooltip"></i>


<!------------------------------------------------------------->

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Icons -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- NOT WORKING BOOTSTRAP VERSION -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- WORKING BOOTSTRAP VERSION -->
<!--
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4.3.1 added a [sanitize option](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2019/02/13/bootstrap-4-3-1-and-3-4-1/) for secutiry that defaults to true. Simply add `sanitize: false` to your options and you're back in business. See also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer:

```js
/** Toolpit */
$(function() {
  $('.my_toolpit').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    title: `Colors explanation:
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='color-box bg-green'></div>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:left;'>Green : available</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='color-box bg-orange'></div>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:left;'>Orange : pre-booked</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='color-box bg-red'></div>
        </td>
        <td style='text-align:left;'>Red : booked</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    `
  });
});


/* Load icons */
feather.replace();
```

```css
.bg-green {
  background: green;
}

.bg-orange {
  background: orange;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.color-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO">


<!------------------------------------------------------------->
<i data-feather="help-circle" class="my_toolpit"></i>


<!------------------------------------------------------------->

<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Icons -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- NOT WORKING BOOTSTRAP VERSION -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- WORKING BOOTSTRAP VERSION -->
<!--
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
```